# Join islands in raster object

Tags: qgis, raster, r, dem

I have a raster with elevation information from the SRTM data. I want to use `topoDistance` to calculate topographic distances between points in this raster. However, there are islands which are not connected to each other or to the mainland, and thus the `topoDist` function cannot connect them. I could convert all empty cells in the raster to some value (like 0, or -1000, or whatever), but that does not necessarily produce the expected paths (what I think humans would likely take) from the `topoDist` function.

What I want, is to join the islands to the mainland and to each other with 'bridges' in the raster, that more or less would be equivalent to navigation routes. The idea being that you travel on land for as much as you can, until you need to cross a water source.

Below is an example from the information I have and what I would like to build (I did this by hand with QGIS).

[image]

And here is the expected result:

[image]

Ideally, I'm looking for solutions with R. So far I have not found anything that can do this. The only solution I have found for connecting all islands is, as mentioned above, to set all empty regions to a fixed value.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new use, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Unfortunately, asking for either of two completely different solution stacks is, in effect, asking two questions. Please choose a stack and detail what you have tried in that environment.

Comment: I have edited the question to an R solution. I have tried finding a solution but I haven't seen anything even related to this issue. Is displaying the rasters in QGIS ok or should I show them in R?

Comment: What makes you think if paths are going to be different to yours if you fill sea surface by zero?

Comment: For example, if I set all sea to 0 and I get the topo distance between the northern most point in the continent (this is La Guajira in Colombia), and the top most island here (I think it's Martinica), then it would be a direct line. In the connections I made by hand, the route would be by land on the top of the continent, and only the last crossing would be by sea. I want topo distances that use land as much as possible, and only route through the sea if absolutely needed.

Comment: In that case, you could use a least cost path and set the cost of the sea to be high.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. The solution is to change the h.dist transition layer.
In the original topoDist function, this is done with:

```
  h.dist <- gdistance::transition(DEM, transitionFunction = function(x){1}, directions = directions, symm = TRUE)
```

To avoid water, we first need to set all water pixels to some value like -10, and then change the above to:

```
h.dist <- gdistance::transition(DEM
                      , transitionFunction = function(x){
                          if((x[1]==0) & (x[2]==0))
                              0.5
                          else
                              1
                      }
                      , directions = directions, symm = TRUE)
```

If we want to force the path through water instead, we change 0.5 to 2.

Edit: This gets me the correct paths, but the distances become all wonky. I'm wondering whether there is a better solution.